# Could not name the movie. Involves drilling into the earth crust but ended up somewhere else

Tags: identify-this-movie

I recall when I was young (in the late 1980's) I saw a snippet of this movie in full-colour, but I can not remember the entire film nor the title.

Now I am older, I wish to know what the movie was about and understand it more. Here is all I know about the film:

It was an action movie.
It is like the latest movie "The Core" which has several people inside a larger drilling machine in the earth. I suspect there was sabotage or some effect from the drilling machine that knocked the driver out and it affected his path of digging into the earth. I recall seeing a dashboard next the driver showing multi-coloured layers which showed the current location where it was at.
It was a colour featured film.
I don't know if there were dinosaurs or large creatures etc.
More like the in the spirit of *Journey to the Centre of the Earth* but not a lot of walking at all.

Hope someone can assist me here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not a perfect match, but it could be [**At The Earth's Core**](http://www.erbzine.com/mag30/3031.html) (1976):

> [image: Poster] <sup>[[Source](http://www.classichorrorcampaign.com/2012/06/04/an-evening-with-caroline-munro/at-the-earths-core-poster/)]</sup>
>
> A Victorian scientist *(Peter Cushing)* and his young American backer *(Doug McClure)* **set off in their new earth-boring machine** for a short test on a Welsh mountain.
>
> **Unfortunately the thing tunnels out of control at ferocious speed and they end up in an enormous cavern at the centre of the earth** - the twilight world of pellucidar.
>
> Here they find prehistoric monsters, man-eating plants and cavemen enslaved to the Meyhas (Mahars) - evil psychic, pterodactyl-type creatures with extra-sensory abilities.

The cockpit includes a display that shows their position:

> [image: Cockpit]
>
> [image: Display] <sup>[[Source](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zG4aGjQnRAo)]</sup>

- [Watch the trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yL7MTLCKgo)

Comment: Yes, that's the one. It makes sense... Interesting I had learnt that Peter Cushing was in Doctor Who now I know he is into this sort of thing. I imagined the budget for this kind of film was very generous.

Comment: Ack - serves me right for being tardy this morning. I could tell you everything you ever wanted to know about this film, I LOVE all the Amicus/AIP flicks. The budget was not huge, but the filmmakers did utilize some unique methods to create the world and the monsters. Campy, rubber-monstery fun.

Comment: I guess the next step is to save a few pennies and watch this on iTunes hopefully with closed captions so I could understand what people may say as I often misinterpret. Rats! iTunes doesn't have the film, only the books. Any ideas where to view this film and see it?

Comment: Try this link Nobby: http://www.amazon.com/At-The-Earths-Core/dp/B001NRW6QK/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1359984709&sr=8-1&keywords=at+the+earth%27s+core

Comment: not the one i was looking for. 80s or early 90's was on tv had a larger group in a drill machine intentionally going to the center. i remember 4 episodes

Comment: @user1924393 http://kickass.to/at-the-earths-core-1976-t4459245.html